# Partner User Error Logging in - Android

Tags: community, authentication, partner-communities, login-errors

We have an issue we are experiencing where Partner/Community Users using an Android device get the following error when trying to log in to the Community on the Salesforce Mobile App.

**Error: Authentication Error. Please try again.**

The app accepts the username and password as correct. Then after you tap Allow for the connected app (Salesforce for Android) to have access, the error appears and it takes you back to the login page.

Any help would be appreciated.